# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) 2D array

Tags: c, valgrind

Hi I have problem with this:

```
tmpy = (int**)realloc(os,y*sizeof(int*));
os = tmpy;
tmpy=NULL;
for(i=0;i<y;i++) {
    tmpx = (int*)realloc(os[i],x*sizeof(int)); 
    os[i] = tmpx;
    tmpx=NULL;
}
```

Program runs good but valgrind gives this error:

```
==12513== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12513==    at 0x402BF0D: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==12513==    by 0x8048760: main (main.c:55)
==12513==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==12513==    at 0x402BF52: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==12513==    by 0x804871E: main (main.c:50)
==12513==
```

What is wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `os` is being `realloc()`d to a larger size, then the additional `int*` effectively added to `os` will be uninitialised pointers (accessed by `os[i]`). These unitialised pointers are eventually passed to `realloc()` within the `for` loop:

```
tmpx = (int*)realloc(os[i],x*sizeof(int));
```

The pointer passed to `realloc()` must be `NULL` or a value previously returned by `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `calloc()`. Set the additional `int*` to `NULL` before entering the `for` loop. Note the cast on return value of `realloc()` is unrequired.